# Using non-namespaces element names from imported schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have created a schema that imports the XHTML 1.1 Strict schema. Many of my elements leverage the `block` and `inline` groups in the XHTML schema.

The problem that I am having is that the XML document I create must use the XHTML namespace in order to successfully validate.

```
<example
  xmlns="http://example.com/example.xsd"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <myElement>
    <xhtml:p>This is my <xhtml:strong>paragraph</xhtml:strong>.</xhtml:p>
  </myElement>
</example>
```

What I would like to do instead is not require the use of the XHTML namespace in my XML documents.

```
<example xmlns="http://example.com/example.xsd">
  <myElement>
    <p>This is my <strong>paragraph</strong>.</p>
  </myElement>
</example>
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Well, then they aren't XHTML elements...You could run your instance XML through an XSLT to transform those XHTML-like elements into XHTML namespace-bound elements, and then validate the output.